# Resin plugin for IntelliJ Ultimate- where is conf folder

Tags: intellij-idea, resin

I just installed Resin plugin for IntelliJ, but I couldn't set the configuration correctly.

Running Resin separately has worked for my application. Here's what I did to configure Resin (**the standalone application**)

1. Download http://www.caucho.com/download/resin-pro-3.1.12.zip
2. Copy some conf files to `C:\resin-pro-3.1.12\conf`

I figured the reason why my IntelliJ's Resin plugin doesn't behave as expected is because I haven't put my conf files into `conf` folder. But, I don't know where `conf` folder is located for Resin plugin for IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just go to `Run` > `Edit Configurations..` > `Resin` > `Configure..` and select default resin configuration file

[image]